# Footer showing in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

A footer (just a thin view with the color of my `CoordinatorLayout`'s background) is shown on scrolling to bottom, as shown in the screen shot:

[image: Screenshot]

I have no idea how that is appearing.

`activity_profile.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.whiz.android.screens.main.ProfileActivity"
    android:background="@color/divider">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_posts"
        >

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

(I am adding a `Fragment` in the `@id/container` that is a simple `RecyclerView`)

Everything is fine when I've scrolled to the top, as:

[image]

Comment: Change the root layout color to the white. it may work ;)

Or remove the margin from the root layout or anywhere you gave.

Comment: I need the background to be gray as it is. Also, I tried removing the margin the only place I have put it (in the `FrameLayout` - `@id/container`) but still the same.

Comment: try to give bottom padding in your cardsview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my `FrameLayout` i.e. the view with the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

So simple.

[(Reference)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189075)